# How Can I get Customer telephone Number for verification/Send SMS Notification as like as email notification for Magento new Customer registration?

Tags: php, magento, sms

01.I try to get Customer Registration form action Here(I have already SMS Api & send sms via php script)

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml

form action="...getPostActionUrl() ..." method="post"

2. sendNewAccountEmail 
   app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php  Line==588
3. Get   protected function _welcomeCustomer in 
   app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php Line==517

Which way i get new Customer telephone number or Send SMS Notification as like as email notification ?

Comment: I want both sms and email notification

Comment: Here is 
[AnsewerHttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192310/magento-sms-both-phone-verification-and-notification/29797156#29797156][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192310/magento-sms-both-phone-verification-and-notification/29797156#29797156

Comment: This extension has the feature you are looking for https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Magento there is `customer_register_success` event trown when customer has been successfully registered.

For handling this even you need to create custom module with observer for this event.

1. Creating **Custom Module**. ( Create new file `YOUR_MODULE.xml` in `app\etc\modules` folder )

Content of `YOUR_MODULE.XML` should look like :

```
     <config>
       <modules>
         <YOUR_MODULE>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </YOUR_MODULE>
      </modules>
   </config>
```

2. Creating **Config File**. ( Create `config.xml` in `app\code\local\YOUR\MODULE\etc` folder )

Content of `config.XML` should look like :

```
<config>
    <modules>
    <YOUR_MODULE>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </YOUR_MODULE>
    </modules>
    <global>
    <models>
        <YOUR_MODULE>
        <class>YOUR_MODULE_Model</class>
        </YOUR_MODULE>
    </models>
    <events>
        <customer_register_success>
        <observers>
            <YOUR_MODULE>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>YOUR_MODULE/observer</class>
            <method>SendSMS</method>
            </YOUR_MODULE>
        </observers>
        </customer_register_success>
    </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

3. Creating **Observer**. ( Create `observer.php` in `app\code\local\YOUR\MODULE\Model\`
    folder )

Content of `observer.php` should look like :

```
<?php
class YOUR_MODULE_Model_Observer
{
    public function SendSMS($observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()-getCustomer();
        $TelephoneNo = $customer->getTelephone(); 
        // At this point you can send this number to your SMS API
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I try this way but not send sms <br/> https://github.com/matinict/Magento_SendSMS

Comment: Try this.
Go to Admin Panel > System > Cache Managment
On the left side, click Select All, and from the dropdown Actions menu select Disable > Submit.

Also note that customer_register_success  event is triggered when customer successfully registered. ( I thnik it will not apply to creating new customer in admin panel, for it you need to handle adminhtml_customer_save_after ). Hope It will help.

Comment: I Disabled Cache but no sms sent

Comment: Are you registering new customer ? Or you are adding customer from admin panel ?

Also go to: Admin Panel > System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled

And add this  `Mage::log('obersver works',null,'test.log' );` code in SendSMS method. If function is being executed you will see `test.log` file in `var/log ` folder.

Comment: registering as new customer before checkout

Comment: No file created in var/log/test.log or anywhere test file 

I put  public function SendSMS($observer) {
    
    Mage::log('obersver works',null,'test.log' );....}

Admin Panel > System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings ==> Enabled
my Compiler Status==>Disabled


system.log
Only Showing this type errror on system.log
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 8: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in lib\Varien\Simplexml\Config.php on line 510

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is attach an observer to the event `customer_save_after`. This will be fired everytime the customer is saved. You will then need to validate if the customer is a new creation.

Then at this point you can trigger the getting of the telephone number and the sending of the sms.

If you want to completely replace the emails with an sms then I would suggest rewriting the classes and replacing the welcome email sending functions with smsm sending functions.

Comment: Thanks ...app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers/CustomerController.php  Line==340


How Can I use  Send welcome to email &&  Send SMS to Telephone Number  
Line==> 340 // Send welcome email....